# valueerror: mutable default <class 'discord.utils._missingsentinel'> for field name is not allowed: use default_factory when imporint discord.ext

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot, but I can't use discord.ext, I have the error in the title and I can't fix it.

```
valueerror: mutable default <class 'discord.utils._missingsentinel'> for field name is not allowed: use default_factory
```

here is what I tried:

- Not importing the discord.py library
- Reinstalling discord.py library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled discord.py then installed it on version 2.0 then installed version 2.1.0 then it worked, tbh I don't know why